# Should I know EJB in order to study CDI

Tags: java, cdi

I was wondering, Should I know EJB as a prerequisite for CDI ? for I've read few CDI samles, found a punch of EJB annotations mixed up with CDI code, If not, Would studying EJB simplifies CDI studying ? 
looking forward to reading your awesome answers, thank you .

Answer (score 1):

CDI is a technology you would use to avoid having to manually figure out the dependencies between your objects. With CDI, you only declare that your objects (classes) is dependent on some other objects (classes). The 'CDI container' will create and inject this dependency for you on the runtime

EJB is a technology that focuses on helping you implementing some common enterprise programming problem (storing & retrieving data, invoking remote method etc.).

As of latest version of Java EE, the recommended way to create/obtain reference to EJB is via CDI, but CDI is also applicable for other resources such as datasources, JMS etc

So yes a little knowledge about EJB would help, but I'd say just limit to the basics, don't go too deep. There are vast amount of technologies within Java landscape. They change very fast, and often overlaps each other, so it's easy to get lost when you're trying to learn one. Just focus on CDI itself for time being.

Comment: AM figuring on going into EJB v.soon, so It's not a bad idea, Zillion thanks, sir .

Answer (score 1):

No EJB is not a prerequisite for CDI but it will help. Refer to this 
[CDI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html) article for clear distinction.